# Filling additional form parameters from one input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm fairly new to Rails and can't find any information on exactly how to do this.

Currently, users create items by filling in a form with URL, Title, Content, etc.

```
@resource = Resource.new(resource_params)
```

.
.
.

```
def resource_params
  params.require(:resource).permit(:title, :url, :content, :name, :tags_as_string)
end
```

I want users to be able to input only the URL, and generate the input for the rest of the parameters using the MetaInspector gem (https://github.com/jaimeiniesta/metainspector), but then be able to go back to the created item and edit its content manually.

Can somebody point me in the right direction? I have a feeling I need to create some kind of helper method, but this is the real first programming I've encountered in my project.

Comment: _"I want users to be able to input only the URL"_ - Then, you need to remove all fields but `url` from your new resource form. And in your controller action `create`, permit only `:url` in params.

Comment: You can have a separate form (with all the fields) for editing a resource and a different set of permitted params for `update` action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent users from passing value of any field except `url`, you will need to remove all fields but url from your new resource form.

*app/views/resources/new.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for(@resource) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :url %>
<% end %>
```

And in your controller action `create`, permit only `:url` in params.

*app/controllers/resources_controller.rb*

```
def create
  @resource = Resource.new(params.require(:resource).permit(:url))
  # Set other attributes using `metainspector`. See documentation for usage.

  if @resource.save
    redirect_to resources_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

You can have a separate form (with all the fields) for editing a resource manually and a different set of permitted params for `update` action.

*app/views/resources/edit.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for(@resource) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :url %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :content %>
  <!-- Add other editable fields here -->
<% end %>
```

*app/controllers/resources_controller.rb*

```
before_action :fetch_resource, only: [:edit, :update]

def update
  if @resource.update_attributes(resource_params)
    redirect_to resources_path
  else
    render :edit
  end
end

private

def fetch_resource
  # Fetch `Resource` instance from database. Homework for you.
end

def resource_params
  params.require(:resource).permit(:title, :url, :content, :name, :tags_as_string)
end
```

**Note:** This code is not tested. It is just to give you hints on how you should proceed. You might have to change some method/field names to make them suit your application.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this tonight.

Comment: Thank you Jagdeep, your pointed me in the right direction. 

I was greatly overthinking things and misunderstood how model object creation works. I was thinking I may have to modify the parameters before they're submitted to Model.new(params)